# How to set a image in android which is fit in 50% of the screen

Tags: android, layout

I want to set an image which will be fit in 50% screen but i can not do this.

Here my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frontImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frontImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you  @shahzain ali